# Looping and checking if MongoDB document exists to create a slug

Tags: node.js, mongodb

If using Node.js and Mongoose to work with mongo. When a user creates a post I have a function that uses regex and removes all non-alphanumeric characters and replaces them with "-". I want to be able to check and see if a document with this slug exists and if so add a  "-2" to my slug and then check again. What's the best way to loop/ check if document exists?

Comment: There are ways, but it basically doesn't seem as wise design. Consider your own question here and the generated url `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36331271/looping-and-checking-if-mongodb-document-exists-to-create-a-slug`. Note the numeric value there right after the "questions" action part of the URI. **That** is the sort of thing you should always be using. It means that is actually the "unique identifier" and actually the **only** thing considered by the controller action. The remaining "slug" is a "throwaway" since it can either be duplicated or changed to something else entirely.

Comment: And, I might add that from an SEO perpective, if that "slug" were changed to make the url `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36331271/why-did-i-not-research-this-question`, then because the "unique identifier" actually remains unchanged, requests to the "old" url will still resolve to the same content. That's how we do good design.